# gvisGeoChart, suppress some tooltip output

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I'm creating a choropleth with *gvisGeoChart* from the following data (named "difference"):

```
State  AIG     AIG_pretty
AL     22186    AL: $22 million
AK    -93065    AK: -$93 million
AZ    659601    AZ: $660 million
AR     14075    AR: $14 million
CA  -1049642    CA: -$1,050 million
CO    591884    CO: $592 million
CT   -187758    CT: -$188 million
DE     49474    DE: $49 million
DC     31559    DC: $32 million
FL   4928379    FL: $4,928 million
GA    150630    GA: $151 million
HI     74427    HI: $74 million
ID    149891    ID: $150 million
IL  -1997777    IL: -$1,998 million
IN   -258058    IN: -$258 million
IA   -217530    IA: -$218 million
KS   -216031    KS: -$216 million
KY     -2444    KY: -$2 million
LA    -53519    LA: -$54 million
ME     70622    ME: $71 million
MD   -232201    MD: -$232 million
MA   -536470    MA: -$536 million
MI  -1052112    MI: -$1,052 million
MN   -356883    MN: -$357 million
MS    -45076    MS: -$45 million
MO   -388473    MO: -$388 million
MT     92241    MT: $92 million
NE   -111284    NE: -$111 million
NV    269201    NV: $269 million
NH     45192    NH: $45 million
NJ  -1679631    NJ: -$1,680 million
NM     29605    NM: $30 million
NY  -3256155    NY: -$3,256 million
NC    876272    NC: $876 million
ND     67850    ND: $68 million
OH  -1262524    OH: -$1,263 million
OK     17140    OK: $17 million
OR    265561    OR: $266 million
PA   -512993    PA: -$513 million
RI   -132706    RI: -$133 million
SC    835055    SC: $835 million
SD     98588    SD: $99 million
TN    457846    TN: $458 million
TX   2399462    TX: $2,399 million
UT     13362    UT: $13 million
VT     -2084    VT: -$2 million
VA     85946    VA: $86 million
WA    599786    WA: $600 million
WV     -9049    WV: -$9 million
WI   -287827    WI: -$288 million
WY     76988    WY: $77 million
```

My googleVis statement is:

```
AIG <- gvisGeoChart(difference, locationvar = "State", colorvar = "AIG",
                hovervar = "AIG_pretty",
                options = list(projection = "lambert", region = "US",
                               resolution = "provinces",
                               colorAxis = "{values:[-4928379, -1355690.39529412, 0, 1355690.39529412, 4928379], colors:['red', 'darkorange', 'white', 'blue', 'darkviolet']}",
                               height = 900 , width = 1200))
```

I want to have the tooltip on mouseover only display "hovervar" (AIG_pretty) and suppress AIG and State. It seems to suppress State automatically, but how do I suppress AIG in the output map?